# Repeat tasklet step until certain condition

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I used Spring batch to build a ETL job. My main job is simply read from a db and write to another one. Before my main job, I need to check a status in the source db to see if it is ready or not. I will proceed with the main job only if the source db is ready. I implemented the check status logic as a Tasklet and I build my job with the simple logic that if check status step failed repeat this step util the step succeed, then proceed with the main job. I build the job as follows:

```
@Bean
public Job myJob(MyListener listener) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName)
                            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                            .listener(listener)
                            .start(checkStatusStep())
                            .on("*").to(mainStep())
                            .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode())
                            .to(checkStatusStep())
                            .end()
                            .build();
}
```

The check status step is a tasklet as follows:

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException {
    //isReady method check the db to see if it is ready
    if (isReady()) {
        //contribution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    } else {
        //contribution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
        return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
    }
}
```

I read the spring batch document and get that the ON method in the conditional follow will check the exit status of the step so that I set the exit status in the StepContribution. What makes me confused is that **when I comment those two lines out and the code still works.**

So my question is, first, if the conditional flow checks the exit status why my code works without explicitly change the exit status? Second, why tasklet return a repeat status and by whom this repeat status is consumed.
Third, is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: i think what you are doing is correct and perfect as per the spring batch framework - the RepeatStatus will be used by the Job - to determine the status of the particular step - and take further action - weather to go to next step , stop job or end job and so on ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the conditional flow checks the exit status why my code works without explicitly change the exit status?

Because by default if the tasklet returns `RepeatStatus.FINISHED`, its exit code will be set to `COMPLETED`

> Second, why tasklet return a repeat status and by whom this repeat status is consumed.

A tasklet is called repeatedly by the `TaskletStep` until it either returns `RepeatStatus.FINISHED` or throws an exception to signal a failure. Each call to a `Tasklet` is wrapped in a transaction. The structure is therefore that of a loop with transaction boundary inside the loop.

> Third, is there a better way to achieve my goal?

IMO, your `Tasklet` implementation is ok as is, you don't need the exit status. Something like:

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException {
   //isReady method check the db to see if it is ready
   if (isReady()) {
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
   } else {
    return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
   }
}
```

This will continuously run until `isReady` is true, so you don't need to implement the iteration with a flow at the job level. The job definition would be:

```
@Bean
public Job myJob(MyListener listener) {

   return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName)
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .listener(listener)
                        .start(checkStatusStep())
                        .next(mainStep())
                        .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.